# Input several ints on one line, return number of ints

Tags: c, input

I'm learning C after having learned Java (among other languages), and I'm somewhat confused about how to handle this simple problem. I need to write a program that will take input in the form of one line. For example, `5 2 75 43 68` (only `int`s), and I need to return the number of `int`s, their sum, and the number of positive and negative numbers.

The problem is that the number of inputs is, obviously, variable--there may be one int or seven, but all will be on one line. I'm not sure how to use C to handle the variable number of inputs. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Combine `fgets`, `strtok` and `strtol`.

Comment: C is so different from Java.... Why do I need to use `fgets`? Why doesn't it work to just pull from `scanf`? For example, using this: `scanf("%s",&str); tok = strtok(str," ");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TO handle variable number of inputs, you need to loop and scanf until you press (Ctrl+D)
Here is an example:

```
int n,sum=0,count=0;
while(scanf("%d",&n)!=EOF)
{
sum=sum+n;
count++;
}
printf("sum=%d,count=%d",sum,count);
```

Note: When you press Ctrl+D, scanf returns -1, and hence the process of taking inputs terminates!

Cheers!

Comment: AFAIR, the value of `EOF` is implementation-dependent, so the sentence `scanf returns -1` isn't quite correct.

Comment: ya added it :P As far as SCANF is concerned, i always get a -1 with EOF ! :)

Comment: And so do I :) But the value `EOF` is still implementation-dependent, at least if to believe [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-file). I need to consult with the Standard...

Answer (score 0):

Input a string, then search for spaces, then convert each number at that position and add it to count and sum. This way, you only need to have the upper limit on the buffer where you're inputting the line; you don't use an array, so you don't need to either limit the number of ints nor do you have to mess with dynamic allocation.

EDIT: In Kerrek SB's format, combine `fgets`, `strchr` and `strtol`. :P

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
char buffer[200];
int numbers[100];
int main() {

    char *ptr;
    int cnt = 0;

    fgets(&buffer[0], 200, stdin); // Get the string

    ptr = strtok(buffer, " "); // Split in every space
    do {
            printf("Number %d: %s\n", cnt, ptr);
            numbers[cnt] = strtol(ptr, NULL, 0); // Grab number
            cnt++;
    } while((ptr = strtok(NULL, " ")));

    printf("Total numbers: %d\n", cnt);

}
```

Comment: Couldn't you just pass a second pointer to strtol() and use that for the starting point for next one - strtol skips spaces and the pointer contains the "next" character after success. So just check if the pointer is at "end of line" (`'\0'` or newline `'\n'`)?

Comment: How does this work? I get most of it, but if it were Java (what I'm used to), `ptr = strtok(buffer, " ");` would perform the full computation and store it in `ptr`, but it doesn't seem to do that since it only outputs one number (string at that point) in the `printf` statement.